# Adding predict output to original dataframe

Tags: r, predict

I have a dataframe that has two columns - year and admission counts. And I have the following code to predict future numbers (for the next 5 years)
(The last year in the dataframe is 1983)

```
df = read.table("C:AdmCounts.txt",header=TRUE)
colnames(df)[1] <- "Year" 
str(df)
model <- lm(AdmCount ~ Year, df)
new.df <- data.frame(Year=c(1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989))
p = predict(model, new.df)
```

The output is

```
       1        2        3        4        5 
62.64909 62.74266 62.83623 62.92980 63.02337
```

How do I add the above output back to the original dataframe to plot a graph? The 1 in the output is year 1985, 2 is 1986 and so on.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify the `AdmCount`, so taking the liberty of choosing the simplest ones possible:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Year = 1985:1989,
  AdmCount = 1:5
)

model <- lm(AdmCount ~ Year, df)
predictDf <- data.frame(Year = 1990:1995)
predictDf$Prediction <- predict(model, predictDf)
```

The above will create a data.frame `predictDf` that will have 2 columns - `Year` with the  years to predict and `Prediction` with the predicted values.

Comment: Thank you. I was then able to use rbind and combine the original and 'predicted' dataframes.